# Adding url parameters to UI component mass action

Tags: magento2.2, uicomponent, massaction

I have a ui component with a listing of products in magento 2.2, with a mass action function implemented.  however when it submits, i need it to also pass over a parameters from the query string.

example listing url: https://mymagentostore.com/admin/wishlist/projects/additem/wishlist_id/1234/

here is my mass action:

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction" >
        <action name="additem">             
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">additem</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add Selected Items to Project</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="wishlist/project/saveitems"/>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add Item</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to add selected item(s) to this projects?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>                    
        </action>
    </massaction>
```

I need to find a way to pass **wishlist_id**=1234 also when the mass action is submitted.

Answer (score 5):

1) Add `class` to attribute to `action`, and replace `url` item with `urlPath`:

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction" >
    <action name="additem" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Action\AddItem">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">additem</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add Selected Items to Project</item>
                <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">wishlist/project/saveitems</item>
                <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add Item</item>
                    <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to add selected item(s) to this projects?</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </action>
</massaction>
```

2) Create class extending the `action` component and implement the `prepare` method. There you can set the URL basing on the param from request (or from anywhere else).

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Action;

class AddItem extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Action
{

    protected $urlBuilder;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = array(),
        array $data = array(),
        $actions = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $components, $data, $actions);

        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function prepare()
    {
        parent::prepare();

        $config = $this->getConfiguration();

        $params = array('wishlist_id' => $this->request->getParam('wishlist_id');

        $config['url'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($config['urlPath'], $params);

        $this->setData('config', $config);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should create class extending the action component and implement the prepare method. Better use $this->redirect->getRefererUrl() to get previous url. It's useful in cases when one ui_component insude anouther one and you want use some params like id and so on.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\MassAction;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Action;

class YourClass extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var RedirectInterface
     */
    protected RedirectInterface $redirect;

    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected UrlInterface $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param RedirectInterface $redirect
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param string[] $components
     * @param string[] $data
     * @param $actions
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        RedirectInterface $redirect,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [],
        $actions = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $components, $data, $actions);

        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function prepare(): void
    {
        parent::prepare();

        $config = $this->getConfiguration();
        $routeParams = null;

        $refererUrl = $this->redirect->getRefererUrl();
        if ($refererUrl && str_contains($refererUrl, 'some_param')) {

            $pattern = '/some_param\/(\d+)/';
            $matches = [];
            preg_match($pattern, $refererUrl, $matches);

            if (!empty($matches[1])) {
                $routeParams = ['some_param' => $matches[1]];
            }
        }

        $config['url'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($config['urlPath'], $routeParams);
        unset($config['urlPath']);
        $this->setData('config', $config);
    }
}
```

Add class to attribute to action and following config:

```
            <massaction name="listing_massaction" >
            <action name="your_class" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\MassAction\YourClass">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">your_class</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your label</item>
                        <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">route/controller/action</item>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Message?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            </massaction>
```