# How to add custom param in url in custom mass action on magento2 grid?

Tags: uicomponent, product-grid, magento2.3.x

I want to add some custom parameters in my custom mass action URL on grid.
I've added mass action but I'm not able to add custom param in URL. 
How I can add custom param in URL?

Comment: using ui component ??

Comment: Yes, I'm using UI component and  I've added custom mass action

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231766/adding-url-parameters-to-ui-component-mass-action

Comment: Try this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231766/adding-url-parameters-to-ui-component-mass-action
Or you can use plugin to edit the param.